# Upper bound of $x\log(x\log(x\log(x\log(...))))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

What is an upper bound (maybe in terms of $x$) of the following sequence as $n\to\infty$?

$$a_0 = x,$$
$$a_{n+1} = x \log a_n$$

Comment: Your recursion is not nesting like you wanted:

$a_1 = x \log x$ but $a_2 =  (x \log x)\log(x \log x)$ You may want to write $a_{n+1} = x \log a_n$ instead

Comment: @ZeroXLR Thanks.

Comment: If the sequence converges, it converges to $a$ such that $a=x\log a$. (But maybe you want to show convergence ?)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think OP wants to find an upper bound in cases where it diverges.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There is no closed-form solution for $a=x\log a$, right? If not, is there any upper bound of $a$?

Answer (score 3):

** some hints**

Put $$f(t)=t\ln(t)$$

$$f'(t)=\ln(t)+1$$

If $0<x\le 1$ then
$a_1\le 0$ and $a_2$ is not defined.

If $1<x<e$ the sequence decreases until becoming undefinite. Some $a_k\le 1$.

If $x=e$, the sequence is stationary.
$$a_n=e$$
Finally, if $x>e$, the sequence will increase to infinity :

By induction, we show that

$$(\forall n>0) \;\; a_n>x$$
and by MVT

$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=(a_{n+1}-a_n)f'(c)$$
$$=(a_{n+1}-a_n)(\ln(c)+1)>(a_{n+1}-a_n)(\ln(x)+1)$$

with $\ln(x)+1>2$.
thus
$$a_{n+1}-a_n>2^n(a_1-x)$$

Comment: Why would the sequence increase to infinity if $x > e$?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated  i just edit an othet hint for that.

Comment: Note that this is the wrong iteration, as in the second iterate $f(f(x))=x\ln(x)\,\ln(x\ln(x))$ instead of $x\ln(x\ln(x))$. In the question the iteration was replaced by a suitable one.

Answer (score 2):

The fixed-point iteration function $g(a)=x\ln(a)$ has derivative $$g'(a)=\frac{x}a.$$ Thus $g$ is contractive in the sense $0<g'(a)<1$ for $a>x$.

The limit, if it exists, can be computed via $$a_*=e^b=bx\iff -be^{-b}=-\frac1x$$ which has solutions using the Lambert-W or poly-logarithmic functions $b=-W_0(-x^{-1})\in(0,1)$ and $b=-W_{-1}(-x^{-1})\ge-1$ for $x\ge e$. Then
$$
a_*=-xW_{-1}(-x^{-1})\ge x
$$
is the only fixed point inside the region $a\in [x,\infty)$ of contraction in the sense $|g(a)-a_*|<|a-a_*|$, and thus the fixed point of the iteration. All sequences $a_{k+1}=g(a_k)$ starting with $a_0\ge x$ will converge toward that point $a_*$.

Answer (score 0):

For $t>0,m>1$, $$\log t\le m(t^{1/m}-1)\le mt^{1/m}.$$
So if $a_n>1$,
$$a_{n+1}=x\log a_n\le mxa_n^{1/m}$$

or

$$\log a_{n+1}\le \log m+\log x+\frac 1m\log a_n.$$

The homogeneous part gives

$$\log a_n= \frac{\log a_0}{m^n},$$ and a general solution is

$$\log a_n\le c\frac{\log a_0}{m^n}+\frac{m}{m-1}(\log m+\log x)$$

or

$$a_n\le \sqrt[m^n]{a_0^c}+\sqrt[m-1]{(\log m+\log x)^m}.$$

Not quite rigorous, but not quite useless...

Comment: What is $c$ above?

Comment: @Harvett: some constant to be determined from initial conditions.

Comment: I don't get it. Why in my computation $c=1$?